# Cakephp 3: How do you sum a foreach loop

Tags: sum, cakephp-3.0

I have an AnnualOperatingBudget table. It has many Budget Expenses.

```
 public function view($id = null)
    {
        $annualOperatingBudget = $this->AnnualOperatingBudgets->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Azinstitutions', 
                          'BudgetExpenses', 
                          'BudgetExpenses.ExpenseTitles']
        ]);

        $this->set('annualOperatingBudget', $annualOperatingBudget );
```

I have a foreach loop in my view.ctp

```
<td class="nonBulletList">

    <?php foreach ($annualOperatingBudget['budget_expenses'] as $expense): ?>

        <li><?= $this->Number->
                       currency($expense->expense, 'USD', ['places' => 1]) ?>
        </li>

   <?php endforeach; ?>

</td>
```

I need to row with the sum of all those expenses.

I tried to add this to my AnnualOperatingBudgetsController:

```
$expenseResult = $annualOperatingBudget->select(
                   ['expense_sum' => $annualOperatingBudget->
                     func()->sum('BudgetExpenses.expense')])->
                     first(); //perform sum for the current year expenses list

$current_year_expenses = $expenseResult->expense_sum; // total sum result of Expenses
```

but I am getting an Error Call to undefined method App\Model\Entity\AnnualOperatingBudget::select()

Comment: Can you make your code a bit more readable please. One liners are difficult to read. See PSR-2 for industry standards https://github.com/php-fig-rectified/fig-rectified-standards/blob/master/PSR-2-R-coding-style-guide-additions.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you're mixing up **Entity** and **Table** functions. Get returns an Entity:

```
 $annualOperatingBudget = $this->AnnualOperatingBudgets->get($id, [
```

You can't call `select` on an Entity, the error is trying to describe that:

```
$annualOperatingBudget->select( // This won't work
```

The `select` function is for a **Query**, which you'll normally get from a **Table**, ex:

```php
// Returns a Query object for the AnnualOperatingBudgets table:
$query = $this->AnnualOperatingBudgets->find();

// Add the select and joins to this query
/* @var \Cake\ORM\Query $query */
$expenseResult = $query
    ->join(['BudgetExpenses'])// To sum on this table, you need to join on it too
    ->select([
        'expense_sum' => $query->func()->sum('BudgetExpenses.expense')
    ])
    ->first(); // Will return one row
```

Another option would be to actually sum the expenses you output directly in the template:

```php
<?php
    $totalExpenses = 0;
    foreach ($annualOperatingBudget['budget_expenses'] as $expense) {
    $totalExpenses += $expense->expense;
?>
<li>
    <?= $this->Number->currency($expense->expense, 'USD', ['places' => 1]) ?>
</li>
<?php }; ?>
</td>
<td>
    <li>
        <?= $totalExpenses ?>
    </li>
</td>
```

Might want to read up a bit on these:

- [Query Builder](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html)
- [Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)

Comment: I took your advice and added it to the view template:  <td><?= $this->Number->currency($totalExpenses, 'USD', ['places' => 1]) ?></td>